# Pass errors from API Respose to Laravel view using Guzzle

Tags: laravel, guzzle

Here's my code:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    try {

        $request->merge(['subject' => 'Subject']);

        $client = new Client(['base_uri' => 'http://crm.vulcan/api/v1/']);

        $res = $client->request('POST','contactForm',[
            'headers' => [
                'Accept' => 'application/json'
            ]
        ]);

    } catch (RequestException $e) {
        return Redirect::route('contact.form')->withErrors($e->getResponse());
    }
}
```

It doesn't work because I can't figure out how the `$e->getResponse()` is supposed to work.

If I do `dd($e->getResponse())` then I get this:

```
Response {#330 ▼
  -reasonPhrase: "Unprocessable Entity"
  -statusCode: 422
  -headers: array:7 [▶]
  -headerLines: array:7 [▶]
  -protocol: "1.1"
  -stream: Stream {#328 ▶}
}
```

The `reasonPhrase` and `statusCode` are exactly what I was expecting, so no problems there.

However, all I actually want is the JSON object from the API which says which fields didn't validate. I know the object is there because I can see it when I sent a POST through Postman. And, bizarrely enough, if I do a return on the exact same `$e->getResponse` then I can see the object, too:

```
{
"name": [
    "The name field is required."
],
"nickname": [
    "The nickname field is required."
],
"email": [
    "The email field is required."
],
"subject": [
    "A subject must be provided"
],
"body-text": [
    "The body-text field is required."
]
}
```

That is exactly what I need to pass to withErrors() and then I'll be done, but I just can't figure out how to do this.

I have a feeling that I'm misunderstanding something regarding streams, but I've read about PSR7 and streams and I'm afraid I do not understand what any of it means or how it's relevant to this particular issue.

**EDIT**

After a bit more fiddling about, I updated the `catch` to the following:

```
        $errors = json_decode($e->getResponse()->getBody()->getContents());

        return Redirect::route('contact.form')->withErrors($errors);
```

That appears to work as I get the JSON object of the errors in a format Laravel can use for the form.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work to handle the HTTP code without throwing an exception:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $request->merge(['subject' => 'Subject']);

    $client = new Guzzle([
        'base_uri' => 'http://crm.vulcan/api/v1/'
    ]);

    $res = $client->request('POST','contactForm',[
        'http_errors'=>false,
        'headers' => [
            'Accept' => 'application/json'
        ]
    ]);

    if ($res->getStatusCode() == 422) {
        //then there should be some validation JSON here;
        $errors = json_decode($res->getBody()->getContents());
    } 

    return Redirect::route('contact.form')->withErrors($errors);
}
```

Comment: That may stop the exception, but it doesn't do anything about the fact that `$e->getResponse()` is still being passed as the `Response` collection I posted above, rather than the JSON object that I actually need.

Comment: It means that instead of having to retrieve the response body from the exception you can get it from your `$res` object as normal as if the http response code was a 200. I have had the same issue myself and couldnt find a way to get the response body out of an exception. I think logically if its expected in this way it kind of isnt an exception so its valid to handle it as I describe

Comment: It doesn't seem as though `'exceptions' => false` is actually disabling exceptions, because the code within the `catch` is still being executed. Furthermore, I still don't have access to `$res`. I managed to overcome the initial problem and I have updated my original question with details. However, I'd still like to try some alternatives as it's a bit of a long-winded command.

Comment: Yeah if its in the catch then I have made a mistake in my referencing in the options array .. http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/request-options.html#http-errors changed my answer should be `http_errors` in the request not the client instantiation

Comment: It's still getting caught by the exception even though I've put `http_errors => false` in the request. I even tried taking it out of the try/catch altogether but it doesn't work. I'm using Guzzle 6.1 so the link you sent is definitely relevant.

Comment: I am on my mobile so can't test it but have had this exact same issue and was resolved like this. I guess I have balled up the reference again. Maybe nested in array called 'options'? Will test when I am back at my machine if you havent cracked it

Comment: I appreciate you putting in so much effort while you are mobile. I'll continue to have a play around with it and see if I can make it work. Like I said in the edit of my question, I have actually got it working now but your suggestion of cancelling out the exception and handling it manually is quite intriguing so I'd like to explore that too.

Comment: Ok, I've got it working without the try/catch. There was a `]` missing from your code and also the presence of the try/catch seemed to be confusing it. Anyway, I hope you don't mind but I edited your answer and marked it as correct. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

I guess, you need to get body contents from response. as [documentation](http://guzzle3.readthedocs.org/http-client/response.html#response-body) says, you can get response body with `$response->getBody()` method, and cast it to `string`.

If you want to parse json response to php array later, you can directly use `$response->json()` method.

In your case, code should look like this:

```
$body = (string) $e->getResponse()->getBody();
// or
$body = $e->getResponse()->json();
```

EDIT: I'm not sure if `$e->getResponse()` return same class instance, as described in documentation. You should be able to get response body from `$res` object, if above code doesn't work.

Comment: `$e->getResponse()->getBody();` works in conjunction with json_decode as I wrote when I updated my answer. However, I definitely can't get `$res` when there's an exception, no matter whatI  try.

Comment: Yes, you are right, you can't get `$res` object in exception. But, I don't get it why there is a `RequestException` when actually, request is sent and response is received. Does it relate to http status code?

Comment: The RequestException is due to the fact that the API has returned a 422 Error because not all of the form fields have been filled in. The API is also Laravel and this is the standard behaviour for when a form submitted via JSON / ajax does not validate.